# Impossible to boot Ubuntu - normal.mod missing

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu (tried 12.04 to 17.10) but I always get the error `error: file /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod not found` then drops me into grub rescue.

I have installed using USB (unetbootin) and CD but get the same result. If I boot from the live CD and browse the HDD the files are actually there.

I have tried boot rescue and it mentions the files are quite far from the start of the disk and the BIOS might not be able to see them? Boot repair supplied a report here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CMynrnmCfD/

I thought it might have been a dodgy HDD but I have tried another one with the same result. I usually never have an issue installing Ubuntu but this PC just refuses.

Comment: This is just a guess. Seeing the boot repair log i didn't find any EFI system partition in your disk. Please make sure whether you have enabled legacy boot instead of UEFI booting in case your computer doesn't support the latter

Comment: It had been set to legacy, I have swapped between the two to see if it would help but neither mode helped. I have never had an issue before the solution was found at the end of the pastebin https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition